# Difficulty with Postgis extension on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I have a updated Ubuntu 14.04 running postgresql 9.3 (installed using the tutorial from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).

When I access my database through pgadmin and go to the console and type:

```
-"create extension postgis;"
```

I get an error that the extension is missing in the directory:

```
 /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control
```

But that is 9.1. - Is pgadmin connected to the wrong postgresql? In my postgresql directory I also have a folder "9.1", "9.2" and "9.3". And the postgis extension files seem to only be in the 9.3 subfolder.

Do I need to change something in the pgadmin settings? I kind of ran out of options myself.

Packages:

- postgis 2.1.2+dfsg-2
- postgresql-9.3-postgis2.1
- postgresql 9.3+154.pgdg14.04+1
- pgadmin3 1.18.1-2
- postgresql-contrib-9.3

**Edit**:

```
 dpkg -L postgresql-9.3-postgis2.1
```

returns:

```
 dpkg-query: Package »postgresql-9.3-postgis2.1« is not installed.
```

but this worked

```
 sudo dpkg -L postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 2.1.2+dfsg-2

    /.
    /usr
    /usr/lib
    /usr/lib/postgresql
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so
    /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so
    /usr/share
    /usr/share/doc
    /usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
    /usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1/copyright
    /usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1/changelog.Debian.gz
```

**Edit 2**:

The server status is also complaining about "The server lacks instrumentation functions" and the missing conbrib-package. Here too the installed package "postgresql-contrib-9.3" is ignored.

[image]

Edit 3:

Output of "pg_lsclusters"

```
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
    9.1 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
    9.3 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

Comment: Please show `dpkg -L postgresql-9.3-postgis2.1`

Comment: @CraigRinger - I got some output now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that is 9.1. - Is pgadmin connected to the wrong postgresql?

Yes.

It appears that you're connected to your 9.1 server, suggesting that 9.1 is still running.

Do `pg_lsclusters` to see what PostgreSQL installs you have and their status.

Each runs on a different port. If you want to connect to 9.3 you need to check what port it runs on and connect PgAdmin to that port.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need all versions of postgresql installed at the same time I would recommend you uninstall them all and then perform a clean installation of PostgreSQL 9.3, postGIS 2.1 and pgAdmin 1.18 and all related packages.

After you should have no problem to associate PostGIS as extension to any PostgreSQL scheme